# Правильна ли фраза "пока, наконец, в палатах не осталось мест..."?

Tags: грамотная-речь

В. Каверин, "Два капитана":

> День тянулся бесконечно, раненые всё прибывали, пока, наконец, в палатах не осталось мест...

Я бы сказал *"пока не кончились места"*. Или всё-таки употребляют так глагол, что *"пока не осталось"* означает без НЕ *"пока оставались"*? Как-то плохо в это верится.

Comment: За что минус?! А ну-ка объясните!

Comment: А вас что больше смущает -  слово 'осталось" или союз "пока не"?

Comment: Ни то, ни другое в отдельности, а сочетание "пока не" с "осталось" вместо противоположного по смыслу слова.

Comment: Союз пока не употребляется:

1)      для указания, что действие главного предложения приостанавливается или прекращается действием придаточного предложения, например: Сердце любит до тех пор, пока не истратит своих сил (Гончаров);

2)      для указания, что действие придаточного предложения происходит как результат того, о чем говорится в главном предложении, например: Казбич выстрелил, с минуту остался неподвижен, пока не убедился, что дал промах (Лермонтов).

Comment: В вашем случае подходит пункт 1. Т. е.раненые перестали пребывать,  как только законились места.

Comment: Проблема в том, что там остались места, а не закончились.

Comment: @Артем, и текста вовсе не следует, что места остались, а ка раз наоборот.  Ср.:Сердце любит до тех пор, пока не истратит своих сил (Гончаров); Здесь, что, тоже имеется в виду: пока истратит?

Comment: @Серж почему, нет, конечно. Истратит и уже не любит. А в моём примере раненые прибывали, пока не что? До тех пор, как закончились места по смыслу. Но читаем: пока не... осталось мест, а не пока не закончились они. "Не" как я писал относится к "пока", железная связка "пока не". Не "пока не + не осталось", а "пока не + осталось".

Comment: Мне кажется, подобные вопросы не корректны. Этак мы и на Пушкина замахнемся((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такое употребление встречается даже у классиков (... *пока не осталось ни крохи.* Салтыков-Щедрин), но редко. В "Корпусе" всего восемь "попаданий" (большая часть - из журналистики, которая, конечно же, эталоном служить не может), при этом все они с усилительной частицей "ни" или с числительным "ни одного". Гуглом находится из современных книжек чуть больше, но попытки обосновать корректность такого выражения наталкиваются на опровержение (см. ниже) и приводят к выводу: да, здесь **не хватает второго отрицания**, которое в виде отдельной частицы неприменимо. Обойти эту трудность можно некоторым усложнением: "пока(, наконец,) не пришло к тому (не вышло так), что мест не осталось". Видимо, интуитивно такую конструкцию пытаются упростить; результат воспринимается удовлетворительно, поскольку без анализа несуразности малозаметны. Ну а встречаемость подобных выражений такова, что эти проблемы, видимо, в большинстве случаев стараются обходить.

---

- ... *пока не осталось два места* (корректное выражение)
- ... *пока не осталось ноль мест* (корректное выражение, поскольку отрицается утверждение "осталось ноль мест")
- ... *пока не осталось (нисколько) мест* (некорректное выражение: "осталось (нисколько) мест" неприменимо как утверждение)

В последнем случае "проваливается" даже такой тест:

> — Сколько осталось мест?
>
> — Нисколько (подразумевается "**не** осталось", поэтому нет утверждения
> "осталось нисколько").

Comment: Спасибо, очень хороший ответ! Вот именно, о том и речь, что когда "не осталось ни" — это совсем другое дело, и, видимо, так говорят или, по крайней мере, говорили раньше иногда. А у меня без "ни", поэтому кажется совсем странным.

Answer (score 1):

В палатах не осталось мест когда? Когда (пока) наконец... Здесь не идёт речь о числе койко-мест, а о всяком месте: не оставалось вовсе никакого свободного места, т. е. полезного пространства или незанятой площади. Множественное число слова можно было бы изменить на единственное (*не осталось места*), но автор полагал, видимо, что мн. ч. более уместно для отражения специфики учреждения.

Comment: Пока (когда) что? В палатах не осталось мест. А не наоборот. А так Вы искажаете порядок, причинно-следственные связи. И даже если "мест" заменить на "места", всё равно, на мой взгляд, фраза будет неправильной — надо "пока, наконец, в палатах не кончилось место".

Comment: В безличном предложении абсолютно правильны сочетания: не осталось мест, не осталось ни одного места, не осталось места. Эти фразы равнозначны. «Кончилось место» — это изумительно. Слова кончаться-оставаться — вспомним о стакане с водой — не взаимозаменяемы.

Comment: Да, действительно, "кончилось место" плохо звучит, если подумать.(( Тогда остаётся заменить на "пока в палатах оставалось место" без НЕ. А что там со стаканом с водой?

Comment: Со стаканом та же история: если стакан воды через край, то места там нету более (или — не осталось, как в вашей палате). «Оставалось, не оставалось» — это что-то новенькое. «Кончилось место» звучит не плохо, а невозможно по определению.

Comment: Повторю то, что написал Жасмин: "не" относится к "пока", а не к "осталось". Вы тоже, видимо, этого так и не поняли.

Answer (score 0):

В ответ внесены изменения.

Союзы ПОКА и КОГДА могут обозначать как одновременность, так и  разновременность событий, что определяется формой  глаголов .

Но  союз ПОКА имеет дополнительную  особенность, так как обозначает **временную границу.**

Есть момент времени: (1) до него места были, (2) после него не осталось мест. Интересно то, что этот момент времени можно обозначить и предложением 1, и предложением 2.

Раненые всё прибывали, пока в палатах **оставались** места.

Раненые всё прибывали, пока наконец в палатах **не осталось** мест.

В словаре обозначен только союз ПОКА (ПОКА НЕ отсутствует).

Из словаря:
ПОКА. II. союз. В то время как; до того времени как. П. сын учится, надо ему помочь. П. солнце не взойдёт, на траве лежит иней. = Сердце любит до тех пор, п. **не истратит своих сил.**

Здесь та же ситуация: два предложения имеют одинаковое содержание:

Сердце любит до тех пор, пока **истратит** свои силы. - Сердце любит до тех пор, пока **не истратит** своих сил.

Comment: Нет, союз "и" не имеет временного значения — временное значение придаёт "наконец". И союз "и" не равносилен союзу "пока". "Пока" в моем (кавериновском) предложении тесно связано с "не".

Comment: Ну да, формально выделяют два союза со значением времени - ПОКА и ПОКА НЕ, но они раскрывают одну тему - фиксируют относительное время событий в СПП.  Мы оставались дома, пока шел дождь. Мы оставались дома, пока не кончился дождь.  Идет дождь - не кончился дождь,  не идет дождь - кончился дождь, это наличие или отсутствие одного и того же действия, которое выражается разными способами: глаголом с частицей НЕ или глаголом с противоположным смыслом. Частица НЕ только условно связана с союзом, в действительности она относится к действию.

Comment: Наречие НАКОНЕЦ передает дополнительный,  но не  основной оттенок временного значения.

Comment: Вы понимаете, что утверждается то, что раненые прибывали до тех пор, как места остались, а не как кончились? "Не" относится к "пока", а не к "осталось".

Answer (score 0):

> День тянулся бесконечно, раненые всё прибывали, пока, наконец, в палатах не осталось мест...

В данном случае "наконец" лучше не выделять запятыми. См. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_436). (Иногда авторы ставят запятые, но я посмотрел в сети эту цитату в нескольких советских изданиях — запятых нигде нет.)

По теме вопроса. Подобное употребление (без второго отрицания) можно найти в книгах:

> Я любил [...] хвататься зубами за подоконник, пока на подоконнике не осталось живого места. (Кен Кизи, "Гаражная распродажа")

"Пока [...] не осталось живого места" встречается довольно часто. Ещё попадается "пока не осталось камня на камне".

P.S. Это было бы лучше оставить в комментариях, но у меня пока нет возможности комментировать.

Comment: Спасибо! Странно это, что встречается такое.